# How to pass data from parent Route to child Route in ngrx Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

I am using @ngrx router and one of the routes has some child routers(basically passing the route parameter) as below:

```
{
path: '/browse',
component: BrowseComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: ':category',
    component: CategoryComponent
  }
]
}
```

The `category` parameter can have values such as "**free**", "**top**", "**paid**", which are routed to using a nav-bar.

But I want to add another category value called "**all**" to be added to the nav-bar which should be the default when the app navigates to "**/browse**" in which case **(I think)** I need to pass some data(an object actually) to the child-route (i.e., "**/browse/all**"). This data is required in child route (essentially the component of the child route) needs to call a service.

I tried with the `index` route by setting the `CategoryComponent` as the `index` for "/browse" as follows

```
{
path: '/browse',
component: BrowseComponent,
index: {
  component: CategoryComponent
},
children: [
  {
    path: ':path',
    component: CategoryComponent
  }
]
}
```

But still I am not sure how do I pass the data from the `BrowseComponent` to `CategoryComponent`. Any thoughts on how do I pass the data from Parent route component to child route component? Or am I doing it wrong and some other better approach can be used to add the **all** category in the child routes.
Thanks

Comment: You can always pass data using a shared service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html I don't know ngrx router or if it provides something built-in

Answer (score 1):

First when you using ngrx you need to think of your Store as ‘single source of truth’. That mean each time you fetch your data, you should retrieve it from the store.

This is right when you playing with your data inside your application.

But if your data come from the outside lets say, querystring, then you should save it to store (by dispatch an action) 
and the other component should fetch these data from the store.

In just angular you can do it by: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

That doesn't mean you not can use these data binding way just consider you have a Store where all your data should be stored.

In your case

```
  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.actionsSubscription = route.params
      .select<string>('path')
      .map(path => new action.SomeAction(path))
      .subscribe(store);
  }
```

I hope it's was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From Victor Savkin's blog post http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router

```
class TeamCmp {
  id: Observable<string>;
  constructor(r: ActivatedRoute) {
    //r.params is an observable
    this.id = r.params.map(r => r.id);
  }
```

Comment: This is a single value Observable which essentially is a string, and is anyway available in the child route.